# Why is the attachment display settings missing?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using elementor/astra theme and currently I am trying to add a custom size for the featured images so they are always hardcropped. I added this code to my child theme functions.php and it did actually work because I can see in generate thumbnails plugin that the tomb-size is there, but I can't set it because I don't have the attachment display settings options on any images. Is there a way to get that to display so I can select from the dropdown my custom size?

```
    /*Custom Image Sizes */ 

add_image_size('tomb-size', 371, 271, TRUE); 


/* Display Custom Image Sizes */ 
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose','redswanio_custom_image_sizes' );
function redswanio_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
return array_merge( $sizes, array(
'tomb-size' => __( 'Cropped Tombstone' ),
) ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding custom image size like this

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
add_image_size( 'horiz-med', 800, 526, true );
add_image_size( 'vert-med', 800, 1050, true );
} );
```